# How to display a json array in table format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a json array with this format:

```
[
    {
        id : "001",
        name : "apple",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "red"
    },
    {
        id : "002",
        name : "melon",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "green"
    },
    {
        id : "003",
        name : "banana",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "yellow"
    }
]
```

Now, I want to parse and display it in table format in Javascript or jQuery. The table has four columns, and each column indicates each attribute of each element in this array. The first row of this table is the name of these four keys. And the other rows are the values of these keys.

I don't know how to write a JavaScript code to achieve this function. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Is there anything that you have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate. https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table the link was already suggested by @Afshin Mehrabani a year ago. Have it a try

Comment: IS that a school assignment? this is the second time I see this exact question, just a different user

Comment: It saddens me to see people answering a question that shows zero research effort :( This question has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: Some one has already provided answer for this,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947067/create-html-table-in-javascript-with-json-or-jquery

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvLHP/3/) I wrote for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17708033/778118) about a month ago...

Comment: I couldn't help myself... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jahroy/FeFau/)

Comment: @jahroy hahahaahahh you nasty time waster heheh :D you made my day! nice done!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/URU5G/1/)

```
var obj=[
        {
            id : "001",
            name : "apple",
            category : "fruit",
            color : "red"
        },
        {
            id : "002",
            name : "melon",
            category : "fruit",
            color : "green"
        },
        {
            id : "003",
            name : "banana",
            category : "fruit",
            color : "yellow"
        }
    ]
    var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
    $("#div1").append(tbl);
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
    {
        var tr="<tr>";
        var td1="<td>"+obj[i]["id"]+"</td>";
        var td2="<td>"+obj[i]["name"]+"</td>";
        var td3="<td>"+obj[i]["color"]+"</td></tr>";

       $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3); 

    }
```

Comment: I am using `.each` and it's displaying only the last value.The `.append` is in a 2 nested .each.
`jQuery.each(arrayobj, function(key, value){ 
 jQuery.each(value, function(label, answer){
 display = '<tr><td>'+label+ '</td><td>' +answer+'</td></tr>'});
});
$('#tbody').append(display);`

Comment: Where are the headers?

Answer (score 11):

using `jquery $.each` you can access all data and also set in table like this

```
<table style="width: 100%">
     <thead>
          <tr>
               <th>Id</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Category</th>
               <th>Color</th>
           </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="tbody">
     </tbody>
</table>

$.each(data, function (index, item) {
     var eachrow = "<tr>"
                 + "<td>" + item[1] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[2] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[3] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[4] + "</td>"
                 + "</tr>";
     $('#tbody').append(eachrow);
});
```

Comment: hey NaYan this isn't working for me..only the last array value is displaying. I am using nested .each.

`jQuery.each(arrayobj, function(key, value){ 
 jQuery.each(value, function(label, answer){
 display = '<tr><td>'+label+ '</td><td>' +answer+'</td></tr>'});
});
$('#tbody').append(display);`

Comment: Hey Banned from SO, your code must be like this: jQuery.each(arrayobj, function(key, value){jQuery.each(value, function(label, answer){display = '<tr><td>' + label + '</td><td>' + answer + '</td></tr>';$('#tbody').append(display);});});

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = [
    {
        id : "001",
        name : "apple",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "red"
    },
    {
        id : "002",
        name : "melon",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "green"
    },
    {
        id : "003",
        name : "banana",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "yellow"
    }
];

for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < length; i++) {
    var temp = '<tr><td>' + data[i].id + '</td>';
    temp+= '<td>' + data[i].name+ '</td>';
    temp+= '<td>' + data[i].category + '</td>';
    temp+= '<td>' + data[i].color + '</td></tr>';
    $('table tbody').append(temp));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var jArr = [
{
    id : "001",
    name : "apple",
    category : "fruit",
    color : "red"
},
{
    id : "002",
    name : "melon",
    category : "fruit",
    color : "green"
},
{
    id : "003",
    name : "banana",
    category : "fruit",
    color : "yellow"
}
]

var tableData = '<table><tr><td>Id</td><td>Name</td><td>Category</td><td>Color</td></tr>';
$.each(jArr, function(index, data) {
 tableData += '<tr><td>'+data.id+'</td><td>'+data.name+'</td><td>'+data.category+'</td><td>'+data.color+'</td></tr>';
});

$('div').html(tableData);
```